# how to prevent losing double quotes in argv?

Tags: c++, console, mingw

Ok, I know I can do loop like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<=argc-1;i++) {
  cout << argv[i] << endl;
}
```

But this way double quotes are lost, that is a string `"something here"` is treated as one element of the args array and quotes are lost.

Ok, I know I can assume quotes if parameter has space inside, but quotes are always lost no matter if there is space or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need the original command line, your can use the  [GetCommandLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function.

Comment: This function retains double quotes.

Comment: Maybe in C++, but I have arrived here looking for the C# version of this method and it doesn't retain double quotes :(

Answer (score 9):

It's the shell that removes the quotes. If you want the shell to pass the quotes to you, you have to escape them:

```
$ ./my-program \"hello\ world\"
```

Note that I escape the space as well, to make it one argument.

Comment: @Joachim Are you sure the mingw tag matches your bash answer?

Comment: @harper Escaping the space doesn't work in a Windows command prompt, but escaping the quotation characters should work in any shell, even the Windows command prompt.

Comment: Yes, it's only a partial answer. I have the impression that this is a strictly Windows related question [http://mingw.org/]. And there is huge difference between shell [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773177(v=VS.85).aspx] and command prompt in Windows.