# How to pass VALID json on the command line to a Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm attempting to pass, as a single command line argument, some valid JSON to my node application.  However, my current attempt is failing because by the time the parameter is passed into my node application, the double quotes have been stripped. This makes the JSON invalid at best, but if there are spaces in any of the property values, it causes serious problems. This example node application will demonstrate the problem:

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

Run this with the following command-line arguments:

```
node test '{"name": "John Doe"}'
```

The output of this command is this:

```
[ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
'C:\\project\\test',
'{name:John',
'Doe}' ]
```

Is there anyway to prevent the double quotes from being stripped away?

Comment: maybe try adding a backslash (\\) before each quote in the command? Maybe escaping it does something...

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but I tried that already as well.

Comment: @threed: according this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830418/how-to-prevent-losing-double-quotes-in-argv you should be able to do it by escaping the quotes

Comment: Ok, that solves part of the problem, but escaping single quotes inside the json doesn't seem to work. (Also, I hate that I did not come across that question in my search; thanks for posting it).