# Quotes and argv in c/c++

Tags: c++, linux

I've seen that the array argv (in c/c++ programs) contains strings which has been strippde by quotes.

So for example, considering the following program:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
      cout << argv[1];
 }
```

When I execute it:

```
 ./prog 'asd'
```

I receive:

```
 asd
```

Is there a way to know wheter a certain parameter were stripped by the quotes (singular or double) in linux, without escaping them (like suggested here [how to prevent losing double quotes in argv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830418/how-to-prevent-losing-double-quotes-in-argv))?

Comment: That code is C++; Please ask a seperate question for C with appropriate code.

Comment: This snippet will exhibit undefined behaviour (UB) if no argument is passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not the C++ runtime that strips the quotes from your string, but the operating system shell (like e.g. Bash). It is the latter that effectively passes the arguments to your program. So, you need to follow the rules of the shell. For example, in Bash, you need to "escape" the quotes

```
./prog \"something\"
```

because the quotes have special meaning. There is no way of "enforcing" the quotes from inside your C++ program, as they are stripped before you run your program.

Comment: do you know any shell which doesn't do this?

Comment: @badnack From the top of my head I don't. I've tried bash, zsh, tcsh, ksh and all do the stripping.

Comment: @badnack This behaviour is required by POSIX.

Comment: @Brian that's why SO is a great site, every day I learn something.

Comment: On Windows, it's actually the C runtime, and you can get the original string by calling GetCommandLine.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The shell actually strips the quotes, not C or C++. It's safe to assume that any member of `argv` that contain whitespace was originally quoted. If it doesn't contain whitespace then there is no way to know.

Answer (score 1):

This actually has nothing to do with C/C++ stripping the quotes.  It's the shell (I assume you are using *nix because of the ./prog).

Try this;

```
echo 'asd'
```

You won't see any quotes.  Quotes enclose an expression so the shell can parse arguments.  If you type:

```
echo '"asd"'
```

Then the outer quotes tell the shell that that whatever is inside is a literal expression.

```
echo "'asd'"
```